# How to check if a string falls under the scope of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, r

if 'A*B*C*D*' is a regular expression, and

```
string <- c("AB"),
```

is there a way to check whether the string is accepted by the regular expression? The kind of answer would be yes or no.

Comment: What would you expect to not match 'A*B*C*D*' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`grep`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

```
> length(grep("^A*B*C*D*$", string)) > 0
[1] TRUE
> length(grep("^A*B*C*D$", string)) > 0
[1] FALSE
```

I've added the `^` and `$` to ensure that only the entire string can be matched. If you don't want that, simply remove them.

Comment: or with `grepl`: `grepl("^A*B*C*D*$", string)`